# Is there any editor using python like emacs to lisp?

Tags: python, emacs, ide

I like the concept and scalablity of Emacs

but I'm not good at Lisp. So I'm finding the similar thing using python.

Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [vim](http://www.vim.org/). You can use python directly in vim script to write your own functions, plugins etc.

Check out [this link](http://brainacle.com/how-to-write-vim-plugins-with-python.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is [pymacs](http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/index.html) which allows you to extend emacs with python.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is [Emacs for python](https://github.com/gabrielelanaro/emacs-for-python), [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), and a whole host of other ide's.  For eclipse you will need to get the [pydev](http://pydev.org/).  I'm including [vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790) here, but from what I know, Emacs users don't like vim.  Check out [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) for more information

Comment: "Emacs users don't like vim." Film at 11! :-) :-)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war

Comment: I think what the OP means is an editor that can be extended using Python not one that supports Python (most do).

Comment: For the record, most vim/emacs users now a days have gotten past the whole childish editor war thing, and freely trade features back and forth.  Also, comparing Eclipse and Emacs is like comparing apples to concrete.